Path on a deployed webapp
I have a problem when I deploy a Java webapp with springboot. My IDE is IntelliJ and i can build the webapp in the IDE for testing, and all works fine but when i deploy it on a tomcat in docker-compose, the path is different so
    public ArrayList<Alergenos> getAlergenos() {
        ArrayList<Alergenos> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        String urlToAlergenos = "src/main/webapp/files/images/alergenos";
        File folder = new File(urlToAlergenos);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
                if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
                    toReturn.add(
                            new Alergenos(
                                    removeSlash(
                                            listOfFile.getName().substring(listOfFile.getName().indexOf("a_"), listOfFile.getName().indexOf(".png"))
                                    ),
                                    listOfFile.getName()
                            )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return (toReturn);
    }

That's my function to get all the pictures of the path, and the path when I deploy the webapp is webappname/files/images/alergenos/(all jpg). What I want is the path to that pictures.
I tried to put the path like "/webappname/files/", "webappname/files/", "/files/" and "files/" but nothing of that works, and i dont know how to fix it.
 2024-08-30T12:00:26.720Z ERROR 1 --- [yokudiet] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [Cannot invoke "jakarta.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath(String)" because "this.servletContext" is null]
tomcat-1  |
tomcat-1  | java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath(String)" because "this.servletContext" is null
tomcat-1  |     at dev.marianof.yokudiet.Controller.MainController.getAlergenos(MainController.java:38) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
tomcat-1  |     at dev.marianof.yokudiet.Controller.WebController.mainPage(WebController.java:35) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
tomcat-1  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
tomcat-1  |     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:124) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:99) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.28]
tomcat-1  |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


I move images/alergenos to src/main/webapp/
demo3
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── DemoJspApplication.java
        │           ├── ServletInitializer.java
        │           ├── HelloJSPController.java
        │           ├── HelloController.java
        │           └── Alergenos.java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── application.properties
        │   ├── static
        │   └── templates
        └── webapp
            ├── images
            │   └── alergenos
            │       ├── a_001.png
            │       ├── a_002.png
            │       └── a_003.png
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── images
                ├── alergenos
                │    ├── a_001.png
                │    ├── a_002.png
                │    └── a_003.png
                └── jsp
                     └── hello.jsp


pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-jsp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo3</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


application.properties
spring.application.name=hello-jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

DemoJspApplication.java
default, created by Spring Boot init (Spring Initializr)
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJspApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(">>> DemoJspApplication start");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJspApplication.class, args);
                System.out.println(">>> DemoJspApplication after run");
    }

}

ServletInitializer.java
default, created by Spring Boot init (Spring Initializr)
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public ServletInitializer(){
            System.out.println(">>> ServletInitializer() init");
        }
        
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                System.out.println(">>> SpringApplicationBuilder configure()");
        return application.sources(DemoJspApplication.class);
    }

}

HelloJSPController.java
Test Controller and JSP
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class HelloJSPController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hellojsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(Map<String, Object> model) {
    
        System.out.println("HelloJSP Controller hello");
        
        model.put("message", "HelloJSP Controller hello");

        // /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
        return new ModelAndView("hello");
    }
}

HelloController.java
YOUR CODE IS TEST IN HERE.
package com.example;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    private String removeSlash(String s1) {
        return ">>>" + s1 + "<<<";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
    public String sayHello(
            @PathVariable String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "greeting", defaultValue = "Hello") String greeting) {
        ArrayList<Alergenos> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();

        String path;

        path = "/WEB-INF/images/alergenos";
        dumpPath("1", path);

        path = "WEB-INF/images/alergenos";
        dumpPath("2", path);

        path = "/images/alergenos";
        dumpPath("3", path);

        path = "images/alergenos";
        dumpPath("4", path);

        String urlToAlergenosWEBINF = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/images/alergenos");
        File folderWEBINF = new File(urlToAlergenosWEBINF);
        System.out.println("urlToAlergenosWEBINF =" + folderWEBINF.getAbsolutePath());

        // String urlToAlergenos = "images/alergenos";
        // File folder = new File(urlToAlergenos);
        // System.out.println("urlToAlergenos =" + folder.getAbsolutePath())
        //     /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/bin/images/alergenos

        String urlToAlergenos = servletContext.getRealPath("/images/alergenos");

        File folder = new File(urlToAlergenos);
        System.out.println("urlToAlergenos =" + folder.getAbsolutePath());

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
                if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
                    System.out.println(">>>>" + listOfFile.getName());
                    toReturn.add(
                            new Alergenos(
                                    removeSlash(
                                            listOfFile.getName().substring(listOfFile.getName().indexOf("a_"), listOfFile.getName().indexOf(".png"))
                                    ),
                                    listOfFile.getName()
                            )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(">>>>FFFFFFF");
        for (Alergenos a1 : toReturn) {
            System.out.println(">>>>" + a1);
        }
        System.out.println(">>>>EEEEEEEE");
        return String.format("%s, %s!", greeting, name);
    }

    private void dumpPath(String id, String path) {
        try {
            Resource resource = null;

            String sURIPath = null;
            String sURLPath = null;

            resource = resourceLoader.getResource(path);
            sURIPath = resource.getURI().getPath();
            sURLPath = resource.getURL().getPath();

            System.out.println(id + ">>> sURIPath  = " + sURIPath);
            System.out.println(id + ">>> sURLPath  = " + sURLPath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}

Alergenos.java
For simulation testing only.
package com.example;

public class Alergenos {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    public Alergenos(String a1, String a2){
        this.setA1(a1);
        this.setA2(a2);
    }

    public String getA1() {
        return a1;
    }

    public void setA1(String a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public String getA2() {
        return a2;
    }

    public void setA2(String a2) {
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alergenos{" +
                "a1='" + a1 + '\'' +
                ", a2='" + a2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


hello.jsp
Test Controller and JSP
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello</title>
    <style>
        .color-red {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<%
// debug
System.out.println("webapp / WEB-INF / jsp / hello.jsp ");
%>
<body>
   <h1 class="color-red">SpringBoot hello.jsp!!  ${message} </h1>
</body>
</html>

src/main/webapp/images/alergenos
( you can access by http://localhost:8080/your-webapp/images/alergenos/a_001.png )

a_001.png
a_002.png
a_003.png

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images/alergenos

a_001.png
a_002.png
a_003.png

Build

package to target/demo3.war

mvn clean package

Put demo3.war to Tomcat 10.1

put demo3.war to Tomcat10.1/webapps

Our Web App in Tomcat Webapps Tree:
apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3
demo3
├── images
│   └── alergenos
│       ├── a_001.png
│       ├── a_002.png
│       └── a_003.png
├── META-INF
└── WEB-INF
    ├── images
    ├── alergenos
    │    ├── a_001.png
    │    ├── a_002.png
    │    └── a_003.png
    ├── jsp
         └── hello.jsp
    ├── classes
    └── lib

Startup Tomcat
cd /your-path/Tomcat10.1/bin/

./startup.sh

Test
curl http://localhost:8080/demo3/hello/AAAA

or Browser open
http://localhost:8080/demo3/hello/AAAA
DEBUG
String urlToAlergenos = "images/alergenos";
File folder = new File(urlToAlergenos);

//ADD THIS TO FIND OUT REAL PATH
System.out.println("urlToAlergenos =" + folder.getAbsolutePath());

Tomcat log
It will fetch from the Tomcat /bin directory as the starting point, which is wrong.
urlToAlergenos =/some-path/your-apache-tomcat-10.1.28/bin/images/alergenos

Change Code
For Tomcat 10.1 + Spring Boot 3.x
Method1 - Use jakarta.servlet.ServletContext

ADD CODE: @Autowired private ServletContext servletContext;
CHANGE CODE: servletContext.getRealPath()

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

  
...
String urlToAlergenos = servletContext.getRealPath("/images/alergenos");

        File folder = new File(urlToAlergenos);
        System.out.println("urlToAlergenos =" + folder.getAbsolutePath());
...

Method2 - Use org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader

ADD CODE: @Autowired private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
CHANGE CODE: servletContext.getRealPath()

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  
...
Resource resource = null;

            String sURIPath = null;
            String sURLPath = null;

            resource = resourceLoader.getResource(path);
            sURIPath = resource.getURI().getPath();
            sURLPath = resource.getURL().getPath();
...

Tomcat log
It will fetch from Tomcat /webapps, our webapp demo3 directory, which is the correct location.
Method 1 - servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/images/alergenos")
String urlToAlergenosWEBINF = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/images/alergenos");
File folderWEBINF = new File(urlToAlergenosWEBINF);
System.out.println("urlToAlergenosWEBINF =" + folderWEBINF.getAbsolutePath());

urlToAlergenosWEBINF =/your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/WEB-INF/images/alergenos


Method 1 - servletContext.getRealPath("/images/alergenos")
String urlToAlergenos = servletContext.getRealPath("/images/alergenos");
File folder = new File(urlToAlergenos);
System.out.println("urlToAlergenos =" + folder.getAbsolutePath());
        
urlToAlergenos =/your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/images/alergenos

Method 2 - resourceLoader.getResource(path);
resource = resourceLoader.getResource(path);
sURIPath = resource.getURI().getPath();
sURLPath = resource.getURL().getPath();

path = "/WEB-INF/images/alergenos";
1>>> sURIPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/WEB-INF/images/alergenos/
1>>> sURLPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/WEB-INF/images/alergenos/

path = "WEB-INF/images/alergenos";
2>>> sURIPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/WEB-INF/images/alergenos/
2>>> sURLPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/WEB-INF/images/alergenos/

path = "/images/alergenos";
3>>> sURIPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/images/alergenos/
3>>> sURLPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/images/alergenos/

path = "images/alergenos";
4>>> sURIPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/images/alergenos/
4>>> sURLPath  = /your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/demo3/images/alergenos/

Please note that I changed the location of the images directory.

Okey, but how can I initalize the servletContext? Because it gives me an error, saying that servletContext is not initialized, i tried to initialize it but i didnt find a way to do it

In my test code, in my rest controller class , add @Autowired private ServletContext servletContext; , I add the code in answser.

I still getting error, i put the error in my question.

@Mariano Fernández Rodero I update my project code. You can build a copy in your environment. JDK 17 + Tomcat 10.1.

@Mariano Fernández Rodero  I add method 2: use org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader get directory.

Okey, with the ResourceLoader its working, thanks.
